# I want to convert sql query to spring jpa criteria api

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, criteria

I have two table. Post and comments

```
create table posts
(
    id             bigint not null primary key,
    description    varchar(8192),
    published_date timestamp(6),
    title          varchar(255)
);

create table comments
(
    id           bigserial primary key,
    comment      varchar(255),
    created_date timestamp(6),
    post_id      bigint constraint fkh4c7lvsc298whoyd4w9ta25cr references posts
);
```

and i want to generate this sql query using jpa criteria api:

```
select count(*)
from (select count(c.*) comment_count, p.*
      from posts p
               left join comments c on p.id = c.post_id
      group by p.id
      having count(c.*) > 1) t
```

this is my a year problem )(.
Thank you in advance!

java code with jpa criteria api